# How to use a tilde character on elementary os

Tags: characters

I want to use a tilde sign but I get a (§) instead ...If I press ´shift´ I get (±) . I am using Elementary OS : Version: 0.2 "Luna" (64-bit)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you get an § instead of ~ when pressing you got the wrong keyboard layout.

I've never done this myself and never tried Elementary OS before but this command should set the default keyboard layout to US:

```
setxkbmap us
```